# Compose xmi files

Tags: xml, parsing, merge, xmi

how can I MERGE fragments of class diagrams represented as XMI files?

I explain the task in the image . in fact each XMI file corresponds to a feature, when I make a configuration, I keep some features and I drop the others. after configuration,  the composer must merge the XMI files that correspond to the features in a single output file (.XMI)
 [Composer SChema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMc9m.png)

Thank you

Comment: Are you using any programming languages?

Comment: Hi @jdweng,  I am using as language XMI, XMI is an XML description of the class diagram